# Calculate datetime between client and server (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, date, timestamp, timezone, utc

I have an application that uses subscriptions for each member that joins. I'm having some issues with dates and calculations related with it. For example, let say a member joins on 2/10/2020 at 10:00. When the user submit the request to the server to process the subscription (the server is using UTC) the date that is being calculate is 2/10/2020 16:00 (because I'm -6:00 hours from UTC). This scenario is OK at this point, because the date is still the same (no matter the time). But, if we replicate this scenario when the user joins for example 2/10/2020 at 19:00, when the request is received and calculate the date, the result is 2/11/2020 01:00, and that produces an error in the invoice because the billing date of the invoice is wrong (one day after). What is the best way to implement this? I have read a lot of this topic, but most of the pages and questions are related in the other way, server to client, to parse of format dates to display to the user.
I have several questions related with this process.

1. Should I sent the date for the UI to the API? Or the timezone and
   based on that, calculate the date in the API? (since the server have
   UTC)
2. Moment.js library have a way to solve this or should be better with vanilla Javascript using Date?
3. Is there any HTTP header for the request to handle the time or date?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what behavior you want to have.  Before you try to fix anything, think through and decide on the exact requirements for what the billing date should be based on.

- Is the user's time zone relevant?  If so, you'll likely need to know what the user's time zone is.  You'll be potentially assigning different dates to different invoices even if they're using the same UTC point in time.  Your business might get confused on why some customers have invoice dates before or after the business day.
- Or maybe the time zone of your company is more relevant? Many business work that way.  All of your invoices will be aligned, but some customers might get confused on why their invoice date is before or after their current date.
- Or maybe some customers snap to time zones of nearby offices, in the case of businesses with offices around the world.

Only you and your company can decide this.  There are probably other options I'm not thinking through here.  It's a business decision, not a technical one.

On your three questions:

1. That depends on what you decide above.
2. Libraries are a good idea for simplifying your code, but they're not a hard requirement.  You can use the `Date` API, if you know what you're doing, but you may find libraries easier to work with.  Also, Moment is in maintainance mode.  For new development, the Moment team recommends you use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) instead of Moment.  There are other popular modern libraries also, including [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) and [js-Joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/).
3. There's the `date` header, but that's not going to help you with this.

Comment: Thank you for your response Matt, I really appreciate it. It helps me a lot to make a decision.